# 301 Redirect from non-existent subdomain to subfolder ( closed wordpress multi-site )

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

About to change a wordpress multi-site with 100+ locations to a standard wordpress site and I'd like to redirect the old closed subdomains to the new specific subfolders relating to those locations.

Because wordpress creates the subdomains dynamically I'm trying to work out if there is a easy way to 301 redirect from the now non-existent subdomains to the new subfolders via htaccess...

https://example1.domain.com.au > https://www.domain.com.au/office-locations/example1

https://example2.domain.com.au > https://www.domain.com.au/office-locations/example2

I'd appreciate any help I've tried a few simple redirect lines like the following with no luck just yet. And i'm not even sure if the .htaccess file in the root folder is best or the one in the main domains public html folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.domain.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com.au/locations/example1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.domain.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com.au/locations/example2 [R=301,L]
```

Cheers and hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.domain.com.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com\.au/example1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for this... I'd created some subdomains on the testing site and was prepared to do it all manual. On creating the new site I tested this out before i got to work and seemed to work just fine... Cheers buddy I owe you an ice cream lol